# UFT not identifying a window in some playback

Tags: testing, vbscript, automation, qtp, hp-uft

I am using descriptive programming in UFT. During playback, I want to check if the Windows print dialog does appear. Then I want to click the Cancel button in that dialog.
My problem: Sporadically QTP fails to identify the printing dialog, so clicking on the cancel button fails.
How can this possibly sometimes fail, sometimes succeed?

My code syntax given below:

```
Set Window_EnterMeter = browser_servicemanager.Window("regexpwndtitle:=Enter Meters.*") 
Set dialog_Print = Window_EnterMeter.Dialog("regexpwndtitle:=Print") 
Set winbtn_CalcelPrint = dialog_Print.WinButton("regexpwndtitle:=Cancel") 

fn chckprintpopupwndow() 
{ ''''''''Navigating to that page 
          call Absolutehighlight(Button_Action) 
          call Absolutehighlight(Meter_Entry) 
          call Absolutehighlight(PrintMeter_Opt2) 
          AbsoluteClick(PrintMeter_Opt2) 
          EnterMeters_Window.WebElement("html id:=ctl00_Save_BTN_C").Click 

'''''''By click on abve option window popup print option appears and UFT not identifying that window all times, so clicking on cancel button not doing so TC fails 
          dialog_Print.Activate 
          AbsoluteClick(winbtn_CalcelPrint) 
          EnterMeters_Window.WebElement("html id:=ctl00_Cancel_BTN_C").Click 
}
```

Comment: You're doing some strange things there, but then I don't know your AUT. The Object Repository isn't entirely evil - is there a reason you can't use it? And do you really need things like AbsoluteClick (whatever it may do) when dealing with perfectly clickable WinButtons?

Comment: Also, fn chckprintpopupwindow() {} is not VBScript/UFT syntax. so where are you actually running this code?

Comment: What kind of syntax is the fn { .. } construct? Did I, for years, miss some exotic VBS syntax properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the root cause of this problem, Actually am running the whole script in a Virtual Machine(VM). During some playback i minimize the VM and work on local system, so during minimizing UFT fails to detect the winobject and also there wont work the (send keys) any keypress events in minimized mode. We can solve the minimize issue by updating the registry edit. For more details go to:-
[can we execute QTP script on remote machine by keeping session minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215543/can-we-execute-qtp-script-on-remote-machine-by-keeping-session-minimized/13370827#13370827)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be related to you storing references to objects before you have navigated to the page on which they exist.

Instead, after clicking on the button that opens the Print dialog try something like this (remembering to put in the relevant object identifiers):

```
Window().Dialog().Activate
AbsoluteClick Window().Dialog().WinButton()
Window().WebElement().Click
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, use .RefreshObject to force QTP to re-identify a test object upon next replay step.

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue like this, Rather than clicking on cancel button on that window i called close property
dialog_Print.Activate 
dialog_Print.Close
This works fine, but still i cant understand why UFT not identifying that window for some playbacks??

And absolute click function is only doing this:
AbsoluteClick(Object)
{    object.Refreshobject
     object.Click   }

and am using this for click in order to avoid another issue of UFT